# Get all lists and list items in a SharePoint site with JSOM

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

I have a SharePoint site and I want to use JSOM to get all lists, and get all items in each list.

I have tried this approach:
Get all lists in the site, store their IDs
For each list ID, get list items

Pseudocode is as such:

```
for each id in listOfIds(){
     executeQueryAsync( context with list ID passed in )
}
```

However, this approach presents a problem for me - the executeQueryAsync only takes the last ID in the listOfIds, presumably because the for loop iterates too fast.

What is the best approach for me to do to get all lists in my SharePoint site, and get all items for each of these lists? I can only use JSOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that scenario:

> to use JSOM to get all lists, and get all items in each list

the following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```
var result = []; 
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
ctx.load(lists,"Include(Id,Title)");

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function() {

       lists.get_data().forEach(function(list){
           var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
           ctx.load(items,"Include(Id,FileRef)");
           var listEntry = {
             id: list.get_id().toString(),
             title: list.get_title()
           }
           result.push({list: listEntry,
                        items: items}); 
       });
       ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function() {
           //transform listitem properties
           result.forEach(function(item){

               item.items = item.items.get_data().map(function(listItem){
                    return listItem.get_fieldValues(); 
               });
           }); 

           console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
       },logError); 


  },logError);
```

where

```
function logError(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Notes:

- the result is stored in `result` array which has the following
  format: `[{list : { id: "1d9b9c27-2b2f-4758-bd7e-f0e4977aa13d", title: "Documents", items: [{ id: "1d9b9c27-2b2f-4758-bd7e-f0e4977aa13d"}, ...]},...]`
- to retrieve list items per every list in a *single request*  [Request Batching feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx) is utilized

Comment: This helps a great deal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using this:

var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

```
function retrieveAllListProperties() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

clientContext.load(collList);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

var listInfo = '';

var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
    listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
}
alert(listInfo);
}

  function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but this only gives me the details of each list. I want to have details of all items in each list too.